# model doesn't have migrations

Tags: django, django-models, django-database, django-datatable

I am working on the Django model. I migrate all the files of the app, but it is showing me the model doesn't have migrations and also no migration file in the folder, but **init**.py file exists in the folder.
Please give me suggestions.

```
admin
[X] 0001_initial
[X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
[X] 0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices
 auth
[X] 0001_initial
[X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
[X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
[X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
   [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
[X] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
[X] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length
[X] 0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length
[X] 0010_alter_group_name_max_length
[X] 0011_update_proxy_permissions
[X] 0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length
 contenttypes
[X] 0001_initial
[X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial
```

Comment: show your project tree structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First delete your all migrations folder and try below command:

```
python manage.py makemigrations appname

python manage.py sqlmigrate appname 0001  #This value will generate after makemigrations

python manage.py migrate
```